# Generate List of string in a Soap Request instead of array

Tags: php, xml, soap

i need to send a list of strings in a XML like this to a soap service with php:

```
<RequestIN xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"> 
   <hashes xsi:type="xsd:string">AAApuVtLmQ20iFvPnFVj/YQBn31KKACnWehYGKg8nrI=</hashes> 
   <hashes xsi:type="xsd:string">BBBpuVtLmQ20iFvPnFVj/YQBn31KKACnWehYGKg8nrI=</hashes>
   ...
```

The definition inside the wsdl is :

```
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="hashes" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
```

the parameters are set with :

```
  $params = new stdClass;
  $params->RequestIN = new MyStructuredClass($hashesArray, ... );
  $result  = $client->MyCall(new SoapParam($params->RequestIN, 'RequestIN'));
```

But if i use a stdClass or Array for generate the RequestIN SoapParameter i get the hash array rappresent like that:

```
<RequestIN xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"> 
   <hashes SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array"> 
      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">AAApuVtLmQ20iFvPnFVj/YQBn31KKACnWehYGKg8nrI=</item> 
      <item xsi:type="xsd:string">BBBpuVtLmQ20iFvPnFVj/YQBn31KKACnWehYGKg8nrI=</item> 
      ...
   </hashes>
   ...
```

How can I generate the first xml with SoapParam or SoapVar ?

Comment: loop through them and add individually instead of an array?

Answer (score 0):

After some test i abandoned the strucured class and create the params one to one with soapVar:

```
    $SendParams =array();
    $SendParams[] = new SoapVar($tid,XSD_STRING,null,null,'exampleField');

    $SendParams[] = new SoapVar($auth,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,null,null,'authUserParam');

    if (is_array(json_decode($hash) )) {
        foreach (json_decode($hash) as $h) {
            $SendParams[] = new SoapVar($h,XSD_STRING,null,null,'hashes');
        }
    } 

    $result  = $client->Call(new SoapVar($SendParams,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,null,null,'MyRequest'));
```

with this approach i finally got the right structure

```
<MyRequest xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct"> 
   <hashes xsi:type="xsd:string">AAApuVtLmQ20iFvPnFVj/YQBn31KKACnWehYGKg8nrI=</hashes> 
   <hashes xsi:type="xsd:string">BBBpuVtLmQ20iFvPnFVj/YQBn31KKACnWehYGKg8nrI=</hashes>
   ...
```

i don't like... but works :/

Open to futher suggestion about structured class